# At which temperature Parmesan cheese must be transported?

Tags: storage-method, cheese, food-transport, parmesan

I bought a piece of Parmesan cheese over internet. When it arrived (in a styrofoam box) I measured its temperature and it was 17,8° C  (64° F). I think it's too high...

Is this OK? What is the correct temperature for storing and transporting Parmesan cheese?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While ideally Parmesan may be stored (at home) in refrigerated environment, there is no harm done to it (assuming nothing else like condensation occurs) by allowing it to sit at a warmer temperature for a few days.  It is, after all, aged at ambient temperature for 2 years.

At least where I live, stores do not even put Parmesan in a refrigerated case; it is sold from tables at room temperature would would be slightly higher than what you measured in the shipping box.

I think your 18 C cheese should be just fine.

See also:  [How to store Parmesan cheese?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25495/how-to-store-parmesan-cheese)

Comment: Thanks! I also saw in Italy Parmesan being sold without refrigerators, but wasn't sure, because for other cheeses  exact prescriptions exist: http://www.tis-gdv.de/tis_e/ware/milchpro/kaese/kaese.htm#temperatur

Comment: Note that the cheeses on the list are all soft, semi-firm, or firm at the hardest; Parmesan is a hard cheese.  Its absence from the list probably tells you the same story as outlined above.