# Storage of Pecorino cheese — is room temperature ok?

Tags: cheese, storage

Is it permissible to store and transport an intact wheel of Pecorino cheese at room temperature for 2 or 3 days before putting it back into refrigeration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [At which temperature Parmesan cheese must be transported?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36932/at-which-temperature-parmesan-cheese-must-be-transported)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. Since Parmesan and Pecorino are both hard cheeses, the answers to the questions are similar, but I wouldn't assume that everybody knows that they're basically the same as far as storage.

Comment: Parmesan and Pecorino are made of different kinds of milk (cow and sheep respectively), so I posted a new question in case storage procedures for products from sheep milk differ from cow milk products.

Comment: Nice save there, buddy! ;)

Comment: @Jolenealaska The definition of a dup is that the answers are the same, even if the asker didn't know it.  I didn't make up that rule.  See for example the turkey stock question closed as a dup for chicken stock.  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37354/chicken-stock-gelatinous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the wheel is intact, 2 or 3 days at room temperature will be fine. Hard cheeses like that are aged at temperatures not far below normal room temperature. If the wheel were cut, if the temperature got above room temperature or if you were asking about a longer period of time, I might be slightly concerned. But in your situation, your cheese will be fine. On the off chance that it develops some mold, cut the mold away with at least a one inch buffer.

Comment: Thank you!  Does the hard cheese require a sealed bag, or is a non-airtight plastic bag OK?

Comment: A still intact wheel? non-airtight is fine.