# Can warm pecorino grow listeria?

Tags: food-safety, cheese

So my mom ordered some pecorino Romano and it came wrapped in insulated bags, foil and  ice packs that had melted. The cheese appeared wet inside the vacuum sealed bag Can pecorino grow listeria after traveling with melted ice packs

Comment: Pecorino doesn't necessarily require refrigeration, but it should be kept cool and dry. Do you know what temperatures were during transit? Was the cheese in a sealed plastic bag, wrapped in paper? Some other packaging?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to read this, but it you might find it helpful:  https://www.mdpi.com/2624-862X/1/3/20/htm

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43834/storage-of-pecorino-cheese-is-room-temperature-ok?rq=1

Comment: I am not sure what temperature the cheese was at after the ice packs had melted and traveled on the postal service truck but it was shipped  and delivered within 3 days . I’m not sure how long those little ice packs hold out